# Concatening string vertically in a DataFrame

Tags: python, dataframe

Given a dataframe of text type, I want to create a new column consisting on the concatenation of all the columns for a specific row (just like in the picture) [image].

The dataframe of this example is given by:

```
  df= pd.DataFrame({'A':['hello word','how are u doing'],'B':['hey!','im doing great'],'C':['lol','lmao']})
```

This can be done with
`df['Joined] = df['A']+df['B']+df['C']`, but I want this to work for different number of columns.  I solved the problem in two different ways:

1.

```
 df['Joined']=''
    for col in du.columns:
        df['Joined']+= ' '+ df[col]
```

2. l = list()
   for index, row in du.iterrows():
   l.append(' '.join([x for x in row]))
   du['Joined'] = l

I would like to know if there is a more elegant way to do this (and more efficient)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
df['Joined'] = df.apply(' '.join, axis=1)
print(df)

# Output
                 A               B     C                               Joined
0       hello word            hey!   lol                  hello word hey! lol
1  how are u doing  im doing great  lmao  how are u doing im doing great lmao
```

**Update**

> If I want the column 'Joined' to be a list of the words instead of the concatenation

```
df['Joined'] = df.apply(list, axis=1)
print(df)

# Output
                 A               B     C                                   Joined
0       hello word            hey!   lol                  [hello word, hey!, lol]
1  how are u doing  im doing great  lmao  [how are u doing, im doing great, lmao]
```

Comment: If I want the column 'Joined' to be a list of the words instead of the concatenation. Is there a way like yours in one step? Obviously this solves the problem 
    df['Joined'] = df.apply(' '.join, axis=1)
    df['Joined'] = df['Joined'].apply(lambda x: x.split())
But I want it in one apply if possible

Comment: I noticed that after applying list over axis=1 I should tokenize my words. This is what I did
```
def ldaparser(df):
    data_words = df.apply(list, axis=1)
    data_words = data_words.apply(lambda corpus : [word for sentence in corpus for word in sentence.split()])
    return data_words
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you want to do with a lambda function

```
df['joined'] = df.apply(lambda r: ' '.join(str(r[col]) for col in df.columns), axis=1)
```